# Give an example of two discrete random variables, X and Y, with the same set of possible values, such that Var(X+Y)≠ Var(X)+Var(Y).

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have tried to give two examples where

X: Rolling a 1 on a 6 sided fair die

and

Y: Flipping a coin with sides labeled 1 and 2.

Both of these random variables have two outcomes but Var(X+Y)= Var(X)+Var(Y)

Comment: $$X=Y{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: But $X$ have the outcomes of $\frac{1}{6}$ or $\frac{5}{6}$ and $Y$ could be $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$. How are they equal? @Did

Comment: The outcome $X=x$ is not the same as the probability Pr$(X=x)$.  Your example is not very clear about the numeric values attained by $X,Y$, so we cannot be sure that these take "the same set of possible values".  Likely you mean that $Y=1$ or $Y=2$ with equal probability, but it's a stretch to say these are the possible values for $X$.

Comment: I see. Thank you @hardmath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity would be true for independent random variables, so you need random variables that are not independent.  In fact, you might try the most extreme case of "not independent", where $X$ and $Y$ are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ independent, then it will certainly hold that $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$. So, you will need to hunt for variables that are dependent. A good source of these would be random variables derived from the same random process, such as letting $X$ be the outcome of a die roll and letting $Y$ be $1$ if that same die roll is even and $0$ if it is odd.